# Processing CURL response

Tags: curl

This is the response that I am getting after curl_exec:

1043475015id.failureFAILresultcode.confirm.ageCan Not Confirm Agefalsefalseid.not.eligible.for.questionsNot Eligible For Questions

What I want is that I want to store each information in separate variables in php, so that I can do some checks and store the values in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expresion to get text in separate values, for example:

```
$d = "1043475015id.failureFAILresultcode.confirm.ageCan Not Confirm Agefalsefalseid.not.eligible.for.questionsNot Eligible For Questions";
$getText = preg_match('/(?<=confirm)\S+/i', $d, $matchText);
print_r($matchText);
```

You will get:

```
Array ( [0] => .ageCan )
```

We this you can create as many variable as you want from each text.